# Fetch data by matching multiple queries MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongodb-query

I want to get the data only when all the query matches.

here is the query to get the data:

```
exports.getParkingListByCriteria = async (req, res) => {
  const cityQuery = req.body.city;
  const stateQuery = req.body.state;
  const countryQuery = req.body.country;

  try {
    const filter = await Parking.find({
      $and: [
        {
          "location.city": { $regex: new RegExp(cityQuery, ($options = "i")), //I want to apply date filter here },
          "location.state": {
            $regex: new RegExp(stateQuery, ($options = "i")),
          },
          "location.country": {
            $regex: new RegExp(countryQuery, ($options = "i")),
          },
        },
      ],
    });

    res.status(200).send(filter);
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(500).json({ error: error.message });
  }
};
```

Date is stored inside of the parking table where it shows the availability of the parking details for that date and time

```
availability: [
      {
        date: {
          type: Date,
        },
        day: {
          type: String,
        },

        startTime: {
          type: Date,
        },
        endTime: {
          type: Date,
        },
      },
    ],
```

collection from the database:

```
{"_id": {"$oid": "62cc46e920782c4be0673d50"},
"merchantId": {"$oid": 62c950ebc96c2b690028be8b"},
"contactInfo": {"name": "Ronda Green", "phoneNumber": 9104933588},
"about": "Laborum non minim ad",
"location":
    {"address": "349 scott avenue",
     "city": "edmund",
     "state": "louisiana",
     "zipCode": 49755,
     "country": "australia"},
"price": 18,
"parkingType": "parkingLot",
"parkingInfo": [{"parkingName": "College Place","_id":"$oid":"62cc46e920782c4be0673d51"},"default": []}],
"totalSpots": [168],
"parkingSpotType": ["Motorbike","Large"],
"coordinates": 
    {"lng": 1.522645,
     "lat": 125.939061},
"status": "active",
"isFeePaid": false,
**"availability": [
       date: "2022-07-10"
       startTime: "7:00"
       endTime:"22:00"
       _id: 62cd048559e9a786ff1df9d7],**
"specialEvents": [],
"__v": 0}
```

I want to show data only when both city criteria and date criteria matches.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking, is it 1. to only return the `availability` field or is it 2. how to add a `date` filter to the query?

Comment: @TomSlabbaert total available parkings based on city and date both (eg. ```"city":'edmund', date:"2022-07-10"```) I should get above result

Answer (score 0):

The question is not very clear. If you want to get the `totalSpots` for each matching document, you can use a simple `find` with a projection:

```
db.collection.find(
{
  "location.city": {$regex: "edmund", $options: "i"},
  "availability.date": "2022-07-10"
},
{
  totalSpots: 1
})
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/FNb4ElVbMrB)

If you want something else, please provide the requested results